# I want to hide div after clicking on close button Angular 6

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

I want to hide div after clicking on close button in Angular 6 and other want to change the other div class.

For example other div class is `col-sm-7`, once close button clicked it will change to `col-sm-12`.

In my component.html

```
<div id="custom-div">
 <button class="close" type="button" click="featureHide()">X</button>
</div>
<div id="another-div" class="col-sm-7"></div>
```

In my component.ts

```
featureHide() {
  document.getElementById('custom-div').style.display='none';
  var element = document.getElementById("another-div");
  element.classList.add("col-sm-12");
}
```

But its not working, please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use Angular [**`[ngClass]`**](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) directive instead:

Here a [stackblitz working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjcfyk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) (remember to expand the browser tab to exceed the `sm` breakpoint)

```
  //Apply [hidden] to hide the button
<div id="custom-div" [hidden]="!isShow" >
  // Use '(click)' instead of 'click' 
  <button class="close" type="button" (click)="featureHide()">X</button>
</div>
  //Apply [ngClass] directive
<div id="another-div" [ngClass]="{'col-sm-7': isShow , 'col-sm-12': !isShow }"></div>
```

In your ts file:

```
isShow = true;

featureHide() {
 this.isShow= false;
};
```

It can also be done the way you tried, but change `click` to `(click)` first, then in your ts:

```
featureHide() {
  document.getElementById('custom-div').style.display = 'none';
  const element = document.getElementById("another-div");
  element.classList.remove("col-sm-7");
  element.classList.add("col-sm-12");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong in angular. Try avoiding document.xxx use angular.xxx.
Please find the below code

In component.html

```
<div id="custom-div">
<button class="close" type="button" (click)="featureHide()">X</button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="hideFalg" id="another-div" class="col-sm-7"></div>
```

In my component.ts
    hideFalg:Boolean  = true

```
featureHide()
{
  this.hideFalg = false; // this code will hide the div element since we have added the *ngIf
}
```

To display div

```
showDiv(){
this.hideFalg = true;
}
```